# GA4: Is it risky if I add a parameter to 'page_view' event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to track some metrics of my webpages (such as the "Average Engagement Time" or the clicks on the ads), switching from one web design to another, by creating a custom dimension in GA4.

I'm a GA4 newbie, and I was told to add a parameter to the 'page_view' event through 'gtag':

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', {'design_option': 'A'});
```

This is, for each one of the designs of the webpages ('A', 'B' or 'C'), I establish a different value for the 'design_option' parameter.

As far as I understand after reading some documentation, the 'page_view' event is one of the GA4's "automatically collected events", linked with the statistics of the views of webpages.

I would like to know if adding a parameter to 'page_view' event is risky or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can add parameters to it and it will all be good as long as the parameters don't exceed the [cardinality limitations](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12226705?hl=en). Also, make sure you know your [event properties limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744?hl=en).

When you exceed the cardinality limitations, it's not too bad either, it just shoves some of the values under the "Other" blanket.